# Get language from nuxt.js middleware

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

Is there a way in nuxt.js middleware to know the language used for the request (of the page)?

By taking the example proposed by nuxt.js (https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-middleware/) and by supposing that for example a page declined in two languages (French and English) with the following urls:

- /fr/ma-page
- /en/my-page

When visiting the first or second url, can we have an indicator on the language used directly in the middleware? Or should you parse the page url to find out (route)?

Because I want to redirect the user according to the language requested...

Comment: What do you mean with page is 'declined'?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `nuxt-i18n` module, is really simple, and you have two ways of doing it. I'll suggest the first, but I think it would be cool to give a perspective on how the module works.

Both of the solutions have the same starting point, getting the `i18n` from the middleware `context`. `i18n` should be accessed from the `app` parameters from the `context`, so we start from here:

```
export default async function({ app: { i18n } }) {}
```

### 1. The best way: letting the `i18n` module do the hard lifting

The same way you can access the translations inside Vue components using the `$t` method, we could use it from the `i18n` object directly.
So if you would write in a Vue Component

```
$t('components.login.register')
```

Then in the middleware you would do

```
i18n.t('components.login.register')
```

### 2. Other option: getting to know the `i18n` module better

If you inspect the `i18n` object that the module exposes, you can find the following parameters is contains:

- `locale` - That represents the current language
- `messages` - An object that keeps the translations for each active language

so you could easily get the previous example translation like this:

```
const { messages, locale } = i18n
const currentTranslations = messages[locale]
const wantedTranslation = currentTranslations.components.login.register
```

I'd suggest for you to use the `i18n.t` module, as it works some of the abstractions you'd need to rewrite yourself, but it's a good example to understand the module better.

Comment: doesn't the i18n.lang require you to already be on the language url itself? ie it gets it from the URL: /en or /de  ...

Comment: @gvanto that's the basic way of implementing it, by relying on the URL path. Although I've seen many use cases in past jobs where the user clicked a link but already had a preferred language setup, or other use cases that would require you to force changing it without any user interaction.

Comment: In those situations you can run into the problem or a infinity loop of language redirection. 

Also, take into account that we should not rely on the URL path but the abstraction already implemented by NUXT to avoid some parallel processing between your code and the library code to change / update language (and shallow updating the URL)